# QGIS WGS84 issues

Tags: qgis, wgs84

I potentially have a problem with my QGIS project, where I am attempting to digitise a relatively small map, and part of the project requires a calculation of the area of each of the parcels of land within the site.

Using the OpenLayers Plugin I added Bing Maps and tried to set it to a different CRS. The results were not pretty so I stuck with WGS84 and digitised away. I then come towards the end of the project, calculated my areas using the Field Calculator '$area' and thought 'I wonder what units it's in?' I would ideally like ha, but a brief look online makes me think the numbers I have are in degrees?? Can these be converted or are they likely to be inaccurate as I'm in the UK and not remotely near the equator?

I am also having problems in the print composer, where the area that I digitised looks fine until it is exported to an image, whereby the boundaries etc are all about 1 cm to the left of where I drew them. Is this another WGS84 hang up?

So my questions really are:
How can I get my maps to look like I drew them? and
How can I get reliable area figures?

Whilst I am comfortable with GIS, I haven't long come to QGIS and a step-by-step guide would be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you did and what went wrong, but:

Openlayers plugin layers should be in EPSG:3857 Pseudo Mercator. This CRS is only useful for displaying web maps, and nothing else.

WGS84 EPSG:4326 is a worldwide usable CRS using degrees as units.

If you want to take measures (length, area, or angle), you should work with a CRS that minimizes distortion. For most parts of the world, you can use the UTM zone system for small-area measurement. For countrywide measures in the UK, you can use the British National Grid EPSG:27700. Elsewhere, you have to look out for other suitable CRS.

If you want to change the CRS in QGIS, **DO** **NOT** use `Rightclick -> Set CRS for Layer`. This will change the CRS, but not recalculate the coordinates. So you might end up with degrees treated as meters.

Instead, choose another **project** CRS, or save your layer to another file name and different CRS.

Comment: Sorry, meant to write EPSG:3857

Comment: Also, I have a fundamental hole in my knowledge of what a good projection is for calculating areas?

Comment: Ok, I have saved the layers into another Project with a  different CRS, but when I re-ran the area calculation all I got was 0.00 for all of them? Any ideas what's gone wrong?

Comment: Best projections for areas would be Albers equal area and lambert azimuthal equal area. You will find the CRS grouped by projection in the CRS list of QGIS. But in most cases UTM will work. For the second one: Have a look at the layer extent, as reported by properties, metadata tab. If it is less than +/- 180/90, coordiantes are still in degrees. **ONLY** in this case use `Set CRS for layer` to restore the right CRS, then `Save As...` to a projected CRS. BTW you should save the data into new data files, not the layers into a new project file.

Comment: Note that OP is in UK, so British National Grid is probably a better choice than UTM.